# Effectiveness of Body Contemplation (Asubha Bhavana)

Tags: personal-practice

Does someone actively practise this type of meditation for a longer period of time? I feel like that it does not really work. Is there something to keep in mind to increase its effectiveness? I think that pictures or even better real life situations are better than self created images in order to see the repulsiveness.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't practise it for a 'longer' time, but I did practise it, it didn't worked because contempletion needs active memory and we really don't have memories of revulsive aspects of bodies.

Then I changed the way, I switched to looking in real world. Following are the things I saw...

1. Meet old people be aware of their bodies, facial features especially, pay attention to the wrinkled skin, stinky weak teeth, bad eye sight, feel the repulsiveness.
2. If you ever happen to be in India visit the place called Varanasi, its the dead body burning ghat for the hindus. Not only they burn it they also just throw it in river to rot, if they are poor. There are also half burned bodies all over. See that sight.
3. Try and attend a stomach surgery or a post mortem at a hospital.

I think this will take you too far with the body contempletion meditation.

And if nothing works contemplate on [this](https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/2_6lbud.htm) story of buddha.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube has enough videos on asubha.